# C++ can't access public members

Tags: c++, class

I'm a new C++ learner.
Given the following code in C++, why I can't access `this.init()` in a function even though it's public?

```
class Complex {

private:
    double re, im;
public:
    void init(double x, double y);
    void add(Complex c);
    double abs(double x)const;
    static int Num;
    Complex(double x,double y=0)
    {
        re=x;
        im=y;
    }
};

double Complex::abs(double x) const {
    //Why I can't access this.init?
    Num++;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't call non-const functions from const functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `abs` function is marked `const`:

```
double Complex::abs(double x) const;
```

and so when is called, the caller object is guarantee not to change, and so if you try to change the value of `Num` compiler won't let you do it, because you are violating the constness of the objects

Comment: So I'm not allowed to do that because in static functions we mustn't change value an only similar const functions promise of not changing the value. But, Let's suppose init() doesn't change the values at all and isn't declared as static why he would refuse to call it? isn't he "smart" enough to know that?

Comment: @clark_smith1 you have to guarantee it to the compiler, by adding "const" at the end of the function declaration, like how you are doing with abs.
As far as i can see, in your code, there is no static function (which by the way, has no sense to const, because there is no `this`)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call non-const functions from const functions